# Best way to increment numbers in one line in Linux

Tags: linux, vim, regex, sed, awk

I have one line with lot of entries among which is also time.

```
 ('DEFAULT',17,NULL,'2014-07-14 10:30:00','Something','2014-07-14 06:30:00',1),('DEFAULT',26,NULL,'2014-07-14 12:00:00','Something2,'2014-07-14 11:00:00',1),...
```

I would like to increment each time by few hours. in 24 h format. For example `10:30:00` would become `15:30:00`.

What is the best universal tool for this job? I am thinking in terms of:

1. system utilities like `awk`, `sed` ..& whatever else I do not know
2. `vim`
3. scripting languages like `bash` or python`

What would be the canonical way to do it?

Comment: Whatever you are comfortable with :) I for example would use perl beucase I'm familiar with it and has really powerfull regexp

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify:

`vim` is a system utility (a text editor) on most *nix systems. `awk`, `sed`, and `bash` are languages (or tools, depending on the context) that you can use to parse and alter text.

What do you need to increment the time for, and how often will you need to increment it? Those factor into what tools you'll want to use. In any case, this is a multi-part effort, ASSUMING THIS IS NOT SQL:

1. You're first matching partial strings within a string. You can use `awk`, `sed`, or `grep -e`, with a regex, to pull those substrings out.
2. When you have those values, you'll convert them to integers (or if you're using a fuller language like python, you might be able to cast them into datetime values using a library). You'll have to do the math you need (and validation, if applicable) to alter those values.
3. Finally, you'll add the replaced values into the line and save the altered file.

Honestly, though, this looks like `sql`, so it might be much easier to use the [built-in tools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) in that language to alter those values.

Comment: You say that `awk` and `sed` are in a whole different category from `vim`?  Are you quoting some reference, or is this just your opinion?  Either way, I disagree; I believe that you’re pointing out a distinction that doesn’t exist.  `awk` and `sed` are utility programs; so is `vim`.  `awk` and `sed` have command languages; do does `vim` (and also `bash`; and, while shells are not normally considered *utility* programs, they certainly are programs).  `awk` and `sed` are programs that you can use to <strike>parse</strike> analyze and alter text; so is `vim`.

Comment: I'm quoting years in the industry using the tools. `vim` is a language the same way Microsoft Word is a language. I'm not interested in arguing semantics with you. I only clarified because the language OP used to describe them suggested an unfamiliarity, and I was trying to help define the terms for them.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good hints in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/addition-with-sed)  suggesting a path of least resistance using a scripting language like Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. which allows intermixing of mathematical and matching operations.

Here is a quick hack with Perl:

```
$ echo '2014-12-05 10:00:10, 1234, 2015-02-01 09:12:24' | perl -pe \
    's/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} )(\d{2})(:\d{2}:\d{2})/join("",$1,$2+3,$3)/eg'
2014-12-05 13:00:10, 1234, 2015-02-01 12:12:24
$
```

In this simplistic example the digit character class (`\d`) followed by the repetition indicator (e.g. `{2}`) is used to capture positional components of the date and we blindly do arithmetic on the hour field. This type of solution is only appropriate when you know your data well enough to ensure that simplistic arithmetic on the hours field will not cause the day to roll over.

Revisiting this problem to address correct date/time arithmetic when the hours field overflows as prompted by @Lieven, the Perl core module `Time::Piece` (Perl>5.8) can be used:

```
$ echo '2014-12-05 22:00:00, 1234, 2015-02-01 09:12:24' | \
    perl -MTime::Piece -pe \
        's/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/( \
            Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%Y-%m-%d %T") \
            + (60*60*3))->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T")/eg'
2014-12-06 01:00:00, 1234, 2015-02-01 12:12:24
$
```

This example input has been updated to show graceful handling of hours values rolling over into the next day. It pulls in the `Time::Piece` module at the command-line, matches off the date-time from the input, converts to `Time::Piece` objects in order to perform date/time arithmetic, then stringify back into the desired output format.

Comment: One might get 99% right using regex but there's no easy way to account for having to increment the day, month or year *(and that's not even touching leap years)*.

Comment: @Lieven_Keersmaekers: constructing date time objects from the match results in order to do this math properly seems reasonable but my first instinct with Perl would be to make a script using box notation and more verbose style to make the intent clearer. As a one liner I figure the best bet is to know your data and determine what transformations will give the desired result.